# Microsoft Graph Toolkit PeoplePicker component returns search result in the wrong order

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using PeoplePicker components from the '@microsoft/mgt-react' library in the React app.
After searching for people, the results are returned in a way that is not acceptable for the requirements.
Example: typing 'tym', I'm expecting all the first names starting with 'tym' to show first in the list and after that other results where surnames start from 'tim'.

Code:

```
   <PeoplePicker
            showMax={showMax}
            ref={ref}
            className={styles.peoplePicker}
            selectedPeople={data}
            selectionChanged={selectionChanged}
            blur={onBlur}
            userType={UserType.user}
          />
```

Instead of it, I receive it in the following way.

[image]

How to reach the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reach your expected result. People picker component is using `$search` [query](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/blob/25175bee70c208f3e0204ec7cbd8cd13c3b7adaf/packages/mgt-components/src/graph/graph.user.ts#L369) to find users by display name or mail. There is no `$orderby` query applied.

The results are sorted by default by [user id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) on the server side.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. The fact is I can see expected result in Teams application, When I enter 'tym' i can see that the list of users is sorted in the following way: 'First names started with 'Tym' and after those users with Last names started with 'Tym'.
But in my app using the same Microsoft account and People Picker component, the search results mash up.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to make a query with the required filters manually and pass it to the component somehow?